# What makes SO think I am a different person each visit?

Tags: support, user-accounts, login

I suspect that it has something to do with cookies.  But with very few exceptions, every question or answer that I post is recorded as being from a "Wes Groleau" who has never posted before.  Including ones I did while logged in with OpenID.  When I don't log in, I spell my name the same, I use the same e-mail address, and it comes through the same web proxy.

I don't give a hoot about reputation and badges, but it does make searching for my past questions more difficult.  And certainly it must degrade the efficacy of all the various logic that depends on how many X points assigned to user Y.

Comment: Can you link to some of these accounts? This is "your" SO account linked to this MSO account - http://stackoverflow.com/users/854073/wgroleau

Comment: *Use the same login each time.*  The account on Stack Overflow that is tied to the account you're using here is an OpenID you created from Launchpad.

Comment: Hmmm... yes, that is an impressive set of accounts (31) - looking...

Comment: All your questions and answers should now be visible [against your SO account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/854073/wgroleau)

Comment: I can't link to the unregistered ones--or can I?  But the ones where I logged in, I used the same OpenID.  I see someone else has posted "Logging in with my openid creates a new account"

Comment: There were two such related posts.  One of them mentioned a site that is inconsistent in the format of their openid strings.  Maybe mine (Launchpad) has the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you have been using unregistered accounts. The system makes it very clear in the text that an unregistered account is tied to your cookies. Simply: make a registered account (which you have now done). I'll merge the other accounts into that (there's plenty of good evidence in the records to satisfy me that they're all the same user, i.e. this one).

Re the "Wes Groleau", well - that came from somewhere. We didn't invent it.

Comment: Yes, they all came from me.  But (1) if all of the fields contain the same strings, why assume they are different people? and (2) Why were some of the ones logged in treated as different people?

Comment: @WGroleau 1: because that has nothing resembling security, 2: there was (IIRC) only 1 "logged in" - the rest were unregistered. The 1 "logged in" *was* reliably known, and I've made that the main account

Comment: 1. Good reason  2. Ah, I remember otherwise, but no big deal.  Thanks